# The xsl:variable element must not have both content and a select attribute

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am wondering what this documentation:

> If the select attribute is present, the  element cannot contain any content

about the xsl:variable element at:

[1]: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_variable.asp%20w3%20schools means?

The reason I ask is because I am encountering this error:

`JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker  - java.lang.RuntimeException: ElemTemplateElement error: The xsl:variable element must not have both content and a select attribute.` during transformation. Weird thing is it "runs" with the eclipse default processor but not xalan.

When it runs with the eclipse default processor, I find that some of the elements in the original document I am converting do not show up in the result document, I am curious if it is related to this. and the eclipse processor just masks the issue while the xalan processor fails.

I believe this is the offending line:

```
            <xsl:variable name="vSections" select="//*[local-name()='ItemDef']/*/*/*[local-name()='SectionLabel'][generate-id() = generate-id(key('kLabelsInForm', concat($vFormOID, '+', .))[1])]">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(., ' ')" />
            </xsl:variable>
```

Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rule is present in both XSLT 1.0 and in 2.0. If you have a stylesheet that contains this error and you find a processor that does not report the error, that's a bug (non-conformance) in the processor. It's not a bug you need to worry about much, just fix the error in your stylesheet.

Comment: I edited the question to show the offending line. How does that piece of code stack up?

Comment: Same answer. The code is clearly wrong, and an XSLT processor that fails to tell you it is wrong has a bug.

Comment: I will take it that the default eclipse XSLT processor has a bug. Thanks for the explanation.